# Python - invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing an ATM code and I am having trouble with a bit of code, which despite my best efforts I cannot fix.
Here is the error message:

```
line 35, in Withdraw
back2_menu = int(input("Do You Wish To Have Another Transation? "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Y'
```

And here is the troublesome piece of code

```
def Withdraw2(self):
    amount = int(input("How Much Do You Wish To Withdraw: \n £"))
    if int(amount) <= self.balance:
        self.balance = self.balance - amount
        print("Withdrawl Accepted. \nYour New Balance Is: £" + str(self.balance))
    else:
        print("Withdrawl Denied. \n You Have £" + str(self.balance) + "Within Your Account")
        again = int(input("Do You Wish To Enter Another Amount"))
        if again in ("Y", "y", "Ye", "ye", "Yes", "yes"):
            print(atm.Withdraw2())
        else:
            backmenu = str(input("Do You Wish To Have Another Transation? "))
            if backmenu in ("Y", "y", "Ye", "ye", "Yes", "yes"):
                print(atm.Menu())
            else:
                print(atm.End())
```

I am just wondering how to fix this so my program runs smoothly.
Many Thanks

Comment: what is `int("Y")` ?

Comment: You are trying to convert a string into an int. Just remove the `int` cast and you'll be fine. `back2_menu = input("Do You Wish To Have Another Transation? ")`. Apply this across your code, I see this error in a couple places.

Answer (score 1):

The int(...) function turns a string integer (i.e. "123") into an integer integer (i.e. 123) without quotes.

"y" does not conform to integer syntax, so int("y") is not valid.

Instead of:

```
again = int(input("Do You Wish To Enter Another Amount"))
```

Do something like a few lines further, and say:

```
again = str(input("Do You Wish To Enter Another Amount"))
```

Then you won't get that error, which is caused by trying to parse out an integer from 'Y'.

Note that the earlier input:

```
amount = int(input("How Much Do You Wish To Withdraw: \n £"))
```

Is valid, if you enter a number. Beware, though, that int(3.4) will truncate to 3.

Comment: You don't need to cast the input into a `str` since input returns a string by default